# Integer cannot be applied error to java.lang.string

Tags: java, android

I'm sure this is a silly problem but I'm new to `java`.
Can anyone see the possible cause of this problem?

```
ArrayList<String> timesTableContent = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        timesTableContent.add(Integer.toString(timesTable + "      X     " + i + "      =     " + i * timesTable));
```

Comment: the code seems to be incomplete, can you check that.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer.toString()` converts an Integer Object to String.

`timesTable + "      X     " + i + "      =     " + i * timesTable` returns a String value by itself. So you can directly add this to your code as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> timesTableContent = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    timesTableContent.add(timesTable + "      X     " + i + "      =     " + i * timesTable);
```

In your code, you are passing a String Object in a method that actually accepts an Integer value. That's the whole problem.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: You are calling Integer.toString() on a String, when the method only accepts an Integer. This is why you get the error message you provided.

I believe you have misplaced your parenthesis a little bit.

You could build the string you want with:

```
ArrayList<String> timesTableContent = new ArrayList<>();

int timesTable = 2;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    timesTableContent.add(timesTable + 
                          "      X     " + 
                                       i + 
                          "      =     " + 
                          (i * timesTable));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use `Integer.toString` call? Try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Integer.toString()` try to concatenate integer using `String.valueOf()`

Instead of

```
ArrayList<String> timesTableContent = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    timesTableContent.add(Integer.toString(timesTable + "      X     " + i + "      =     " + i * timesTable));
```

Replace this

```
ArrayList<String> timesTableContent = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    timesTableContent.add(timesTable + "      X     " + String.valueOf(i) + "      =     " + String.valueOf(i * timesTable)));
}
```

**But instead of use this**

Just concatenate without convert it. Thanks